# Why do I have so few classified labels

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

In my dataset I have 300k rows, I do a 70/30 split and the result seems to be an alright model, until i view the true-positive, false-negative, false-positive and true-negative numbers.

TP is 20, FN is 2. FP is 3 and TN is 41.

That's extremely low? So the results a great, but if the model were only able to classify 66 of 90 000 is rather useless.

What can I do to improve this? Two Class Boosted decision tree or neural net does not change the outcome that much. Any recommendations?

Comment: Is this a binary classification? Can you please share the experiment link here?

Answer (score 0):

can you please check if you have any missing values in your dataset?